# Sql query to add the line missing in the original query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a query to get the payroll run results-

```
Query #1-
SELECT  
       employeenumber, 
       effective_date, 
       classificationname, 
       Sum(currentamount) AS currentamount,  
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' THEN NULL 
         ELSE Sum(hours_value) 
       END                hours, 
       Avg(rate)          Rate, 
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' 
         THEN Sum(hours_value) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END                UNITS, 
       job_name,
       payroll_action_id
FROM   xyz
```

Now, this query gives the output like -

```
employeenumber      effective_date      currentamount   UNITS       job_name        element name                    payroll_action_id
    100             2020-07-03          200             1           Supervisor      Meals 10 Earnings Results       456
    100             2020-05-08          100             2           Supervisor      Meals 10 Earnings Results       574
```

There is another table which will have the Payroll balances for this employee. This will include the same currentamount like - 200,100 and the ones that are not included in the above query.

```
Payroll_balance table - 
    
    PERSON_NUMBER   BALANCE_NAME    BALANCE_VALUE   EFFECTIVE_DATE      payroll_action_id               
    100             Meals Units     200             2020-07-03          456 
    100             Meals Units     100             2020-05-08          574
    100             Meals Units     350             2020-01-01          578
```

The payroll_action_id is common between these two tables. The payroll_action_id that is not included in the query #1(578) should be added
by using Payroll_balance  query

```
Expected output - 


 employeenumber     effective_date      currentamount   UNITS       job_name        element name                    payroll_action_id
    100             2020-07-03          200             1           Supervisor      Meals 10 Earnings Results       456
    100             2020-05-08          100             2           Supervisor      Meals 10 Earnings Results       574
    100             2020-01-01          350                         Supervisor      Meals Units                     578
    
How can this be achieved ?
```

Comment: Your query is malformed -- it has aggregation functions but no `group by`.  That makes the entire query a bit hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

One way to get expected output is `LEFT JOIN` with `NVL` check on each column.
LEFT join will make sure you consider all records from `payroll_balance` table. `NVL` will replace your NULL values with actual one from `payroll_balance` table.

For demonstration purpose, I have explained first four columns (one of each type). Please check below SQL and extend the solution. However I am not clear about aggregation logic with no `GROUP BY` or `WINDOW` clause in your original SQL.

```
SELECT  
       nvl(x.employeenumber,p pb.erson_number), 
       nvl(x.effective_date, p.effective_date),  
       Case when x.employeenumber is not null then Sum(currentamount) else sum(balance_value) end AS currentamount,  
       nvl(x.payroll_action_id, pb.payroll_action_id)
FROM   payroll_balance pb
Left join xyz x on pb.payroll_action_id = x.payroll_action_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT B.*,A.*
FROM
(SELECT  
       employeenumber, 
       effective_date, 
       classificationname, 
       SUM(currentamount) AS currentamount,  
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' THEN NULL 
         ELSE Sum(hours_value) 
       END                hours, 
       AVG(rate)          Rate, 
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' 
         THEN Sum(hours_value) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END                UNITS, 
       job_name,
       payroll_action_id
FROM   xyz 
GROUP BY  employeenumber, 
       effective_date, 
       classificationname, 
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' THEN NULL 
         ELSE Sum(hours_value) 
       END,              
       CASE 
         WHEN earnings LIKE '%Meals 10 Earnings%' 
         THEN Sum(hours_value) 
         ELSE NULL 
       END, 
       job_name,
       payroll_action_id) A
RIGHT JOIN Payroll_balance B ON A.payroll_action_id=B.payroll_action_id
```

This is assumed query where in it looks like you need all the values from Payroll_Balance and matching rows from xyz table.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 common ideas:

#1 via UNION ALL

```
select * from <original query 1>
union all
select * from <all records from balance table that not exists in query1 >
```

something like query below, but details of implementation depends on your real data

```
/*original "xyz" part*/   
select * from <query1>    
UNION ALL
/*second "balance" part*/
select PERSON_NUMBER as employeenumber, BALANCE_VALUE as currentamount, EFFECTIVE_DATE, null as UNITS
,... as job_name, BALANCE_NAME as element name
 from Payroll_balance
   where not exists 
(select * from xyz 
  where xyz.employeenumber =  Payroll_balance.PERSON_NUMBER
    and xyz.currentamount =  Payroll_balance.BALANCE_VALUE
    and xyz.effective_date =  Payroll_balance.effective_date
    and xyz.payroll_action_id = Payroll_balance.payroll_action_id
)
```

#2 via FULL OUTER JOIN

```
select nvl(xyz.employeenumbe, Payroll_balance.PERSON_NUMBER) as xyz.employeenumber
from <... query1...>
 full outer join Payroll_balance on 
xyz.employeenumber =  Payroll_balance.PERSON_NUMBER
        and xyz.currentamount =  Payroll_balance.BALANCE_VALUE
        and xyz.effective_date =  Payroll_balance.effective_date
        and xyz.payroll_action_id = Payroll_balance.payroll_action_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you 2nd table as abc and first table xyz:

```
Select coalesce(abc.PERSON_NUMBER, xyz.employeenumber) employee_number, 
abc.EFFECTIVE_DATE, abc.balance_value currentamount   
coalesce(xyz.job_name, abc.job_name)
coalesce(bc.BALANCE_NAME,xyz.element_name) element_name, 
payroll_action_id
from abc LEFT OUTER JOIN xyz ON abc.payroll_action_id = xyz.payroll_action_id
```

Comment: why the hard coded value 578 ? it should work for all cases